# I need to integrate Google cloud translation API to google sheets using macros

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-docs

I Cant find any workable solution. Can anyone help? Need to make translate from 1st sheet in one doc to the second. About 60.000 changeable rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Translate function directly in your sheet

[image]

If you want more advanced/customized calls, I recently [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/call-cloud-run-from-app-script-the-easy-way-70677086efa1) where I use the current user credential and I call a Google Cloud API (not the translate, but the principle is the same)